# NuGet - T4 File properties are different after installed

Tags: c#, .net, t4, nuget

I'm building a NuGet package that delivers some T4 templates into the CodeTemplates directory. When I install the NuGet package, the T4 templates all have the Custom Tool property set to "TextTemplatingFileGenerator". This isn't right.

I know I can disable this by altering my registry so that new T4 templates aren't added this way, but since this is a NuGet package, that is not an option.

I've looked into PowerShell, but I'm having trouble understanding what I would do to achieve my goal.

I've looked at the .csproj file xml and found this:

```
<None Include="CodeTemplates\AddController\Controller.tt">
    <Generator>TextTemplatingFileGenerator</Generator>
    <LastGenOutput>Controller.cs</LastGenOutput>
</None>
```

If I remove "TextTemplatingFileGenerator" from this node, then the file will work as I desire.

Where should I go from here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure there's a nice way to do this. In a blog post, [David Ebbo wrote](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2009/07/17/two-ways-to-use-t4-templates-support-code-vs-one-time-generation.aspx):

> One last thing I’ll mention about this
>   model is that the .tt file is normally
>   not part of your project.  Instead, it
>   lives somewhere else, and only its
>   output becomes part of your project. 
>   Well, technically, the .tt file can be
>   in your project for easy editing, but
>   you then have to remove the
>   ‘TextTemplatingFileGenerator’ custom
>   tool, because you really don’t want it
>   to execute on its own (it would surely
>   fail with the custom host).

This makes it sound like this is Visual Studio behavior when a .tt file is added to the project.

That said, [Scott Hanselman's AddMvc3ToWebForms](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/AddMvc3ToWebForms) makes some changes to a GUID in the csproj file to add MVC functionality (Add Controller / Add View, etc.), so it's possible you could do something similar to his code and remove the `Generator` section for files in your package and reload the project?

Comment: It sounds like you have some knowledge about the subject, but this doesn't really address my problem. I am definitely looking to keep the T4 templates as part of the project. That is the only way that I know of to override the default view and controller templates in MVC. Plus I have some other templates besides these that I want to live inside the project.

Comment: I don't think there's a nice way to do what you want, short of automating VS to change the types after they're added. The AddMvc3ToWebForms package manupilates the project file to change a GUID - maybe you can do something similar to change the custom tool against each file you add?

Comment: Yeah, that's probably what I'll do. I was hoping that someone could help with that.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I solved it using "install.ps1" which executes everytime the nuget package is installed or updated.

Your install.ps1 should look like:

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

$addControllerFolder = $project.ProjectItems.Item("CodeTemplates").ProjectItems.Item("AddController")

$addControllerFolder.ProjectItems.Item("Controller.tt").Properties.Item("CustomTool").Value = ""
```

Comment: I haven't tried this because I haven't dealt with this issue for years now, but I'm glad somebody followed up with something that might work. This was a frustrating problem.