# Installing T4 Template in NuGet Package Creates Compile Errors

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget, t4, envdte

I am creating a NuGet Package that has T4 templates within it.  Upon installation of my NuGet package, the T4 templates execute immediately, as they are decorated with "TextTemplatingFileGenerator" as the default Custom Tool.

There is a perfect solution to removing the Custom Tool during the NuGet installation by user Subgurim here: 
[NuGet - T4 File properties are different after installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997199/nuget-t4-file-properties-are-different-after-installed)

This does remove the Custom Tool attribute from the .TT files of my NuGet package.  However, at this point, they have already executed and my Error List is full of errors from the failed execution of these files.

Is there a way of either clearing the Error List after successful installation of my NuGet package and/or stopping Visual Studio from running the T4 templates during installation, so that these errors do not get listed?